# Why does libgit2 expose GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT as a credential type to the credential callback?

Tags: kerberos, ntlm, libgit2, winhttp

I've got a naive question about GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT. Why is it exposed to the credential callback that the clients have to implement? Can the transports not just handle this for the caller?

A server response is giving me both GIT_HTTP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE and GIT_HTTP_AUTH_NTLM, so the allowed credential types of GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT and GIT_CREDENTIAL_USERPASS_PLAINTEXT are sent to the callback. Unfortunately I check for GIT_CREDENTIAL_USERPASS_PLAINTEXT ahead of GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT. Should I just always be checking if GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT is an allowed type first and trying that before other credential types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just always be checking if GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT is an allowed type first and trying that before other credential types?

Probably?  This really depends on the user experience that you want to support, but I think that this is what most users would expect.

If you were in a kerberized environment, then as a user, you would probably just expect single-signon to happen.

You will probably need to keep some state here, however, in case you supply `GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT` in your callback and then the authentication *fails*.  In this scenario, you may want to try `GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT` first and then prompt for username/password if that fails.  (Instead of getting caught in an infinite loop just blindly trying `GIT_CREDENTIAL_DEFAULT` in your callback.  You can use the the payload on the options structure to hold this state.)

> Why is it exposed to the credential callback that the clients have to implement? Can the transports not just handle this for the caller?

This is a bit of a philosophical question.

The thinking of libgit2 here is that we should not decide how to authenticate for you, the application.  You can imagine that a Git GUI might try to connect to a server and then pop up a dialog that asks you how to authenticate.  Maybe you want to select the currently logged in user *or* override that with a custom username/password.

If you *didn't* want to support single sign-on then either we would need to give you an option that says you don't want it, or we need to give you the data in a credential callback so that you can choose to act on it.  This is a judgement call, admittedly, but the latter seemed more in keeping with the way the library tends to work.

Comment: Yes, state is definitely required across calls to the credential callback. An interesting situation I got into was with GIT_CREDENTIAL_USERPASS_PLAINTEXT, where I'll optionally call out to "git credential fill" to retrieve credentials. If Git-Credential-Manager-Core is the manager then it will return an empty username and password if single-sign on 'works'. Obviously returning that to the server does no good :D